# Bare metal kubernetes DNS not forwarding

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, bare-metal

I have a bare metal kubernetes cluster set up for my own education purposes. It's three VMs - one master, two workers, running Ubuntu 20.04. I'm having problems with pods forwarding DNS requests.

CoreDNS is running

```
kubectl get po --all-namespaces |grep dns
kube-system      coredns-74ff55c5b-cdvcv                   1/1     Running   11         4d
```

It has an expected cluster IP

```
kubectl get svc kube-dns -n kube-system
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   4d
```

However it cannot resolve names, such as this attempt on master node:

```
nslookup github.com 10.96.0.10
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

** server can't find github.com: SERVFAIL
```

If I edit ConfigMap.yaml

```
forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
    max_concurrent 1000
}
```

to `forward . 8.8.8.8 {` then it will work.

```
nslookup github.com 10.96.0.10
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   github.com
Address: 140.82.112.3
```

However this won't resolve private LAN DNS names, obviously. I need CoreDNS to forward to the DNS of the machine it runs on.

I am running k8s 1.20.3, which as I understand no longer has a problem with an infinite loop due to Ubuntu's stub `resolv.conf`. Besides I've tried brute force deleting the symlink `/etc/resolv.conf` and recreating it to point to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` on each VM, reboot each, and nothing improved.

I discovered that a pod cannot ping the host machine's DNS (192.168.149.2), so it seems like that's the issue, but I don't know what to do about it.

What else should I be looking at?

Comment: Complete guess, in hopes of impacting the iptable, I installed https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/ip-masq-agent/, and this changed something. The pods can now ping other 192.168.149.xxx (worker machine) IPs. But still cannot ping 192.168.149.2 the DNS of these machines.

Comment: Whats your ClusterIP subnet for pods?

Comment: The cluster is mostly the defaults of a new install - 10.0.0.0/8

Comment: 10.0.0.0/8 overlaps 10.96.0.10/16 for serivce subnet. So is it 10.0.0.0/8 or are you just not sure and giving me close but not very specific answer

Comment: - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12

Comment: Also    - --cluster-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
in kube-controller-manager.yaml

Comment: Notice your node has 192.168.149.2 which is in the same subnet as your cluster-cidr. It must not be in the same subnet.

Comment: use different subnet for cluster-cidr. Make sure NONE of subnets in your network overlap. So for example use --cluster-cidr="10.244.0.0/16". To do this you may need to recreate the cluster

Comment: Do you know if editing /etc/kubernetes/manifests is the best place to make this change?

Comment: It's not that ease. If you want to do it by hand, you may want to have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176343/how-to-make-the-pod-cidr-range-larger-in-kubernetes-cluster-deployed-with-kubead But since you have only 3 vms, its faster to just recreate the cluster

Answer (score 1):

Resolved per [Matt's](https://serverfault.com/users/545145/matt) clues.

Pay close attention to initial cluster setup. Instructions online might lead you to overlook an overlapped IP range. Kubernetes private IPs must be separate from private IPs external to the cluster.

Use a tool like `kubectl run curl-busybox --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty --rm` to `curl`, `nslookup` and `ip a` which gives some visibility to the pod's view of the network.